# Restrict Codeigniter session creation in table for particular user agent

Tags: php, android, mysql, codeigniter

I tried lot before posting the question. I couldn't find solution for my problem. Please help any one.
I'm having application developed by codeigniter. This application having user login page, when user login with user details session will be create and store into session table.

```
$data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('user_name'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

when i use the above code codeigniter automatically insert into my session table(dt_usersession).

If anyone try to login with same user name and password i can inform them like some other already logged in with same details. If he/she wants to login i will ask them to enter their security key to close their previous session in table and i will allow to login current user. 
I will check for every 2min from ajax whether current session alive or not, if not page will terminate and redirect to login page. This will perfectly working for my web application.

And also i'm having android application when i call my codeigniter controller from android new session create frequently( for every call new session create in table).
So when i check for every min whether any others login with same user name and password my session table continuously creating new row. So my server load getting increase. Because more number of users using my application so creating new records multiple times for every user request. How to solve this issue, Please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **MY_Session** class in the */application/libraries* folder and override the default config files depending on a conditional like so:

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {
    
    public function __construct() {
       if(User::isLoggedIn()) 
       {
            $params = array(
                "sess_use_database" => true,
                "sess_table_name" => "CI_Session" // ... all other settings you may need
            );
       }
       else 
       { 
           $params = array(); 
       }
       
       // initialize parent session with correct params
       parent::__construct($params);
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you may want to create your own table for sessions (outside of CI bounds) and just store the logged in user's ID, the session ID ( `session_id()` [see manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) ) and the timestamp and keep checking agains that table while leaving the CI sessions alone.